# Почему div располагаются один за другим, а не заменяют друг друга в Карусели Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Очень долго разбираюсь с этой проблемой, нужна помощь опытных. 
Я использую bootstrap 4 версии Alpha. Проблема заключается в том, что у меня отображаются сразу три картинки, причем они расположены в столбик. При переходе на новый слайд, у меня, буквально на секунду, исчезает предыдущая картинка, но потом весь исходный список возвращается на место. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы один div заменял другой, причем в строке. Не могу понять, в чем проблема.
В качестве дополнительной информации: все лежит в контейнере .container в блоке `<div class="row">.`
Причем проблема заключается не только в карусели. В других случаях такая же проблема с расположением , заменяющих друг друга.
Заранее спасибо.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide ">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="C://Users\Снежа\WebstormProjects\untitled13\src\img\man.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>АДАПТИВНАЯ ВЕРСТКА</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img  src="C://Users\Снежа\WebstormProjects\untitled13\src\img\man2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img  src="C://Users\Снежа\WebstormProjects\untitled13\src\img\man3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>

$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: 6000});
```

Comment: Здравствуйте **снежа**! Вы пишите что у вас карусель работает, но не так как нужно, поэтому, пожалуйста, сделайте ваш код воспроизводимым, чтобы ту ошибку что вы описываете, можно было увидеть в действии. Это серьезно увеличит ваши шансы на то, что кто-нибудь ответит и поможет вам с этим. Всего вам доброго!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте правильность подключения скриптов и стилей, проверьте пути файлов, подключен ли jquery.

Все работает:

```js
$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: 6000});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide ">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>АДАПТИВНАЯ ВЕРСТКА</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img  src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200/" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img  src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

p.s: версия альфа

Comment: огромное вам спасибо! Действительно, дело было в подключении скриптов :) благодарю